# OneToMany relation with multiple properties in JSP form

Tags: java, forms, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I have this model:

**Order.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`order`")
public class Order {
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "order")
    private List<OrderProduct> orderProducts;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new Long(id).hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Order)) {
            return false;
        }
        return this.id == ((Order) obj).getId();
    }

    /* getters & setters */
}
```

**OrderProduct.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_product")
public class OrderProduct {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Long quantity;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private Order order;

    /* getters & setters */
}
```

And this controller:

**OrderController.java**

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"products"})
public class OrderController {
    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;

    @Autowired
    private SecurityService securityService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/order/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addOrder(Model model) {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setOrderProducts(new AutoPopulatingList<>(OrderProduct.class));
        model.addAttribute("orderForm", order);
        model.addAttribute("products", productService.findAll());
        return "order/add";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/order/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addOrder(@ModelAttribute("orderForm") Order orderForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        orderForm.setUser(userService.findByUsername(securityService.findLoggedInUsername()));
        for (OrderProduct orderProduct : orderForm.getOrderProducts()) {
            orderProduct.setOrder(orderForm);
        }
        orderService.save(orderForm);
        return "redirect:/order/view";
    }
}
```

And I want to create a form where a user can choose few products, give a quantity of them and submit his order. I was trying to write JSP code like that:

```html
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="orderForm">
    <spring:bind path="orderProducts">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
                    <form:checkbox path="orderProducts[${product.id}].name"
                        value="${product.name}"
                        label="${product.name}"/>
                    <form:input type="text" path="orderProducts[${product.id}].quantity" placeholder="Quantity"/>
                </c:forEach>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </spring:bind>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form:form>
```

...but unfortunately it's probably trying to create as many orderProducts as I have in products list and as a result the orderProducts, which a service try to save, doesn't have properly setted values and at the end there is created an order without the orderProducts. So my question is how can I properly send the orderProducts via JSP code to the controller which finally will create the right order with its items?

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting this ${product.id}. As this is an index value, it should be like 
orderProducts[0].name orderProducts[0].quantity 
orderProducts[1].name orderProducts[1].quantity 
orderProducts[2].name orderProducts[2].quantity

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing an orderProducts from an orderForm which don't have a quantity properly setted in my OrderController but probably it isn't the best solution.